# Exclude scss files from karma

Tags: webpack, karma-runner, karma-mocha, webpack-3

I want karma to completely ignore/not care/be completely oblivious to style files.

I've got the following in my webpack config, which causes webpack to not import the files during build.

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\.(less|scss)$/), // ignore styles when running specs
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/client\/utils/), // ignore polyfills
],
```

However, when Karma runs, it tries to execute the imports, which of course fail:

`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./view.scss"`

I've tried adding pretty much very permutation of exclude in my karma config

```
exclude: [
    {
        pattern: '**/*.less',
        type: 'module',
    },
    {
        pattern: '**/*.scss',
        type: 'module',
    },
]
```

And I tried [ignore-styles](https://github.com/bkonkle/ignore-styles) (which throws an error out of the box).

I just want it to skip the styles files because they have nothing to do with the tests and just waste time building. I don't understand how this is so difficult.

## Sample project with failure

https://github.com/JakobJingleheimer/fetch-mock-test
(sorry, npm install might have a few extra packages).

When you run the tests, you should get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./test.scss" at webpack:///…/src/client/TestComponent.jsx:3:0
```

Comment: Are u using css modules?

Comment: No, I'm using scss (and also semantic-ui-less) `import './view.scss';` (in SomeView.jsx)

Comment: Do you have a special `webpack.config` file for karma? If so, you can configure to use `null-loader` for `*.scss` files

Comment: Yes, I have a `webpack.config.test` and `webpack.config.coverage` (which both export an object containing only the `plugins` shown above). What're you looking for?

Answer (score 6):

You can configure your `webpack.config` file that you pass to `karma-webpack` to use [`null-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/null-loader) as a `*.scss` file loader.

Something like that:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss/,
        use: 'null-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I installed `null-loader` and pasted that into both webpack.config files, but I still get the same cannot file module error.

Comment: can you share small code with the error (on github)

Comment: what kind of code? the webpack.config and/or karma.config?

Comment: If that possible, small proj with one test and karma + webpack config that reproduces the problem

Comment: sure. it'll probably take a bit to put together.

Comment: https://github.com/jshado1/fetch-mock-test (sorry, npm install might have extra packages listed). When you run the tests, you should get the following error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./test.scss" at webpack:///…/src/client/TestComponent.jsx:3:0`

Comment: Hi, sorry, I wasn't able to fix it :\